# comparing http_referer against http_host

Tags: asp.net, contains, request.servervariables

Hi
I need to check whether the http_referer is the same site as the current site.

I have the following code

```
Dim strReferer As String

strReferer = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")
If strReferer.Contains(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")) then
   'do task
End If
```

This is throwing up an error saying - "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**" and flagging the if line as the offending line of code.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

MY SOLUTION:

```
strReferer = "" & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")
```

Means the string always has a value even if it's nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `HTTP_REFERER` is not always populated - only if you have clicked a link. So if you browse directly to a page, that header will be empty.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")` to be `null`, so you should check for this when assigning the variable.

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER"))
    'do your stuff
```